# At what quests/points in time do each of Deckard Cain's talk options become available?

Tags: diablo-iii, achievements

I'm missing some of the talks with Deckard Cain  and want to know when they can be made. To make this question more informative, I ask for all the different conversations that are needed for the achievment.

Comment: Link to all conversation achievements http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/72159/how-to-collect-all-diablo-3-conversation-achievements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Available Dialogues in Diablo 3 for Deckard Cain

**Who Are You?**

Available at the start of the quest: A Shattered Crown

**Prophecy of the End Days**

Available at the start of the quest: A Shattered Crown

**Your Adopted Niece**

Available at the start of the quest: A Shattered Crown

**Mad King Leoric**

Available at the start of the quest: A Shattered Crown
Disappears at the start of Sword of the Stranger

**The Mysterious Stranger**

Available at the start of the quest: Sword of the Stranger
Disappears at the start of the Broken Blade
*Not needed for conversation achievement.

**The Archangel Tyrael**

Available at the start of the quest: Sword of the Stranger

**The Horadrim**

Available at the start of the quest: The Broken Blade

**Origins of the Coven**

Available at the start of the quest: The Broken Blade

**The Worldstone**

Available after the end of the quest: The Broken Blade
Inaccessible at the start of The Doom of Wortham.
*NOTE: You can use the quest choose method to start at the beginning of Doom of Wortham, just don't talk to The Stranger, since when the quest officially starts, Deckard can't be talked to anymore.

**Leah and Cain's Travels**

Available after the end of the quest: The Broken Blade
Inaccessible at the start of The Doom of Wortham.
*NOTE: See above for details about the last 3 convos.

Taken from http://soe.hubpages.com/hub/Deckard-Cain-Lore-and-Character-Dialogue-Guide-Diablo-3

Comment: Why am i getting a downvote? The person asked for the achievement details, i gave him one.

Comment: @ I'm only interested in the time frame when it's open and prerequisites. Please edit and rearrange your answer to be more readable, and not just a copy paste from a blog. See example here: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/63584/where-do-i-find-leahs-journal.

Comment: Edited. Hope that suits your reading needs.

Comment: Now can i get a upvote please? Lmao.

Answer (score 4):

I did a run through with a new character, noting when each of the conversations became available. There are a few that the exact point in the quest is not 100% because a friend joined and I didn't want to hold them up by running back after every single objective. Once you've heard a conversation, if it was missable, it seems to stay around in stead so until I go through with another character and don't talk to anyone, I can't be certain when exactly they can be missed.

Deckard Cain's conversations are only in Act I and since you can't speak to him after he enters his house once *The Doom in Wortham* starts, that's definitely when all conversations with him have certainly been missed.

### Act I

- **Who Are You?**: Available after accepting the quest *A Shattered Crown*.
- **Prophecy of the End Days**: Available after accepting the quest *A Shattered Crown*.
- **Your Adopted Neice**: Available after accepting the quest *A Shattered Crown*.
- **Mad King Leoric**: Available after accepting the quest *A Shattered Crown*.
- **The Mysterious Stranger**: Available as part of the end of *Reign of the Black King*.
- **The Horadrim**: Available after accepting the quest *Sword of the Stranger*.

  - **The Archangel Tyrael**: Available after hearing the conversation *The Horadrim*.
- **Origins of the Coven**: Available from the time after you complete the quest *Sword of the Stranger* and before you accept the quest *The Broken Blade*.
- **Leah and Cain's Travels**: Sometime during the quest *The Broken Blade*. It might be related to Leah's conversation *Leah's Childhood* so I'll have to do some testing.
- **The Worldstone**: Sometime during the quest *The Broken Blade* I don't have the specific objective on this one.

  - **Destruction of the Worldstone**: Available after hearing *the conversation The Worldstone*.

Comment: you do know you're answering something that's already been answered, right?

Comment: @RenoYeo Is the answer wrong? There's nothing anywhere that says that a question cannot have multiple answers or that questions with accepted answers cannot get more. In fact stack exchange openly encourages having more answers than questions. Also, the posted answer is missing Destruction of the Worldstone and does not indicate that The Archangel Tyrael appears after hearing *The Horadrim*.

Comment: @RenoYeo If I find the accepted answer to be wrong, I will post a correct answer.

Comment: creating questions which already exist serves no purpose here when there are already answers out there.

Comment: @RenoYeo Who said anything about creating questions? I admit, I did create a question because this one didn't come up when I searched for it. It has now been closed and searches will direct to this question.

Comment: and if anything is wrong towards an accepted answer, there's always an edit button.

Comment: @RenoYeo Actually there isn't always an edit button. Not all users have sufficient reputation to edit someone else's answer. Also, I believe that my answer and effort spent researching the answer differentiates it from the accepted answer which merely referenced someone else's unverified information sufficiently to post it as a separate answer.

Comment: right. to each his own.

Comment: If I find an answer with several bullet points is just missing one, I leave a comment for the answerer to update it instead of posting a 95% dup; just a personal opinion :p

Comment: @Alok You are entitled to your opinion. I also believe my answer to be more readable because you don't have to scroll just to read them. Additionally, that one point is not the only thing wrong. More like 85% dup. It should be noted though that my answer ***is not wrong*** and in being both more complete and more correct than the accepted answer should be more useful to future users.

Comment: Never said its wrong; and just fyi I didn't downvote this just commenting on my approach - I'd rather see a single answer than multiples and have to go through them all :)