# When can I get Deckard Cain's conversations for the Stay Awhile and Listen achievement?

Tags: diablo-iii, achievements

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [At what quests/points in time do each of Deckard Cain's talk options become available?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/71400/at-what-quests-points-in-time-do-each-of-deckard-cains-talk-options-become-avai)

The achievement says to "Listen to all of Deckard Cain's conversations." In order to not miss any, I'd like to know when they become available and if and when they are no longer available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a run through with a new character, noting when each of the conversations became available. There are a few that the exact point in the quest is not 100% because a friend joined and I didn't want to hold them up by running back after every single objective. Once you've heard a conversation, if it was missable, it seems to stay around in stead so until I go through with another character and don't talk to anyone, I can't be certain when exactly they can be missed.

Deckard Cain's conversations are only in Act I and since you can't speak to him after he enters his house once *The Doom in Wortham* starts, that's definitely when all conversations with him have certainly been missed.

### Act I

- Who Are You?: Available from when you start *Shattered Crown*.
- Prophecy of the End Days: When you start *Shattered Crown*.
- Your Adopted Neice: When you start *Shattered Crown*.
- Mad King Leoric: When you start *Shattered Crown*.
- The Mysterious Stranger: You get this conversation at the end of *Reign of the Black King*.
- The Horadrim: When you start *Sword of the Stranger*.

  - The Archangel Tyrael: After hearing *The Horadrim*.
- Origins of the Coven: Before you start *The Broken Blade*.
- Leah and Cain's Travels: Sometime during *The Broken Blade*. It might be related to Leah's conversation *Leah's Childhood* so I'll have to do some testing.
- The Worldstone: Sometime during *The Broken Blade* I don't have the specific objective on this one.

  - Destruction of the Worldstone: After hearing *The Worldstone*.

Answer (score 0):

This is available in other questions that ive answered, but here:

Available Dialogues in Diablo 3 for Deckard Cain

**Who Are You?**

Available at the start of the quest: A Shattered Crown

**Prophecy of the End Days**

Available at the start of the quest: A Shattered Crown

**Your Adopted Niece**

Available at the start of the quest: A Shattered Crown

**Mad King Leoric**

Available at the start of the quest: A Shattered Crown
Disappears at the start of Sword of the Stranger

**The Mysterious Stranger**

Available at the start of the quest: Sword of the Stranger
Disappears at the start of the Broken Blade
*Not needed for conversation achievement.

**The Archangel Tyrael**

Available at the start of the quest: Sword of the Stranger

**The Horadrim**

Available at the start of the quest: The Broken Blade

**Origins of the Coven**

Available at the start of the quest: The Broken Blade

**The Worldstone**

Available after the end of the quest: The Broken Blade
Inaccessible at the start of The Doom of Wortham.
*NOTE: You can use the quest choose method to start at the beginning of Doom of Wortham, just don't talk to The Stranger, since when the quest officially starts, Deckard can't be talked to anymore.

**Leah and Cain's Travels**

Available after the end of the quest: The Broken Blade
Inaccessible at the start of The Doom of Wortham.
*NOTE: See above for details about the last 3 convos.

Taken from http://soe.hubpages.com/hub/Deckard-Cain-Lore-and-Character-Dialogue-Guide-Diablo-3

Comment: remember to accept if its what you want!